# Podman vs Buildah: buildah from, run, and commit -versus- podman run, exec, and commit?

Tags: container, podman, buildah

It seems we have the workflow to launch a container, and run commands inside of it, and commit it.

```
buildah-from - Creates a new working container, either from scratch or using a specified image as a starting point.
buildah-run - Run a command inside of the container.
buildah-commit - Create an image from a working container.
```

But we can do the same thing with `podman`?

```
podman-run - Run a command in a new container
podman-exec - Execute a command in a running container
podman-commit - Create new image based on the changed container
```

What's the difference between these two sequences of commands? When should we prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 2):

> Podman does do builds and for those familiar with Docker, the build
> process is the same. You can either build using a Dockerfile using
> `podman build` or you can run a container and make lots of changes and
> then commit those changes to a new image tag. Buildah can be described
> as a superset of commands related to creating and managing container
> images and, therefore, it has much finer-grained control over images.
> Podman’s `build` command contains a subset of the Buildah
> functionality. It uses the same code as Buildah for building.

Taken from: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/02/21/podman-and-buildah-for-docker-users/